# Find the locus of a point which moves so that the sum of the squares of its distances from the lines $x + y = 0$ and $x - y = 0$ is $4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, locus

I have tried answering this question and my answer is $x^2+y^2=2$ yet the book says $x^2+y^2=4$. Help please.

Comment: If you show what you have done, we may be able to spot an error in your work. If you show what you have done, we may be able to see that your method is not the appropriate one and we may be able to send you on the right track. But if you don't show your work, we would only be able to give you a solution or a hint which may not be appropriate for what you already know.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to _find_ any such points? If you do, you will see that the book is right. And you can then work backwards to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the image below, it apparent that the locus you want is a circular arc, because for any angle $\alpha$, the sum of the squares $a^2+b^2=R^2$ and hence the circular arc must be $x^2+y^2=R^2=4$ or $R=2$.[image]